# C++ project reference in a C# project in visual studio 2008

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio

Is is possible to reference a C++ project in a C# Project?  I've tried adding a reference in the c# project to that C++ one but I get an error saying "A reference to  could not be added"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your C++ project is a native (standard C++) project, then no.  If it's a managed project, you can add a reference to it.

For native code, you'll need to use [P/Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468(VS.71).aspx) to access functions within the C++ DLL.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot reference native DLLs directly. You could only if you compiled it for the CLI (targetting .NET CLR) or had build a COM component (in which case VS builds an interop DLL automatically). Otherwise no way, you would have to write a wrapper DLL.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](http://www.vdanet.be/research/resources/on-the-mixing-of-c-c-c-and-lisp-code/) webpage. It's a very good article on the mixing of C, C++, C# and Lisp code with short examples. Unfortunatelly the C++ -> C# is possible mostly when you use managed C++.
Short example ([from earlier mentioned webpage](http://www.vdanet.be/research/resources/on-the-mixing-of-c-c-c-and-lisp-code/)) which shows how to call the C++ managed Adder class from C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace Dllcaller
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Adder a = new Adder();
            Console.WriteLine(a.add(1, 7));
            while (true) ;
        }
    }
}
```